# How to stop Python program by hand in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, exit, try-except

I have a `try-except` block of code in my program, that doesn't stop after running it. I tried `spyder, sublima3, vs-code` IDEs but none of them could stop it after running. How can I fix my code that I can stop it by pressing stop button?

```
import time 
import datetime
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os, sys


path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/filter/crawled/'
#list_file = str(os.listdir(path))
list_file = list(set([f for f in os.listdir (path)]))
list_file.sort(key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(path, x)).st_mtime)
xlsx_file = []
for item in list_file:
    if item.endswith('.xlsx'):
        xlsx_file.append(item)
while(datetime.datetime.now().time() >= datetime.time(8,30,00) and datetime.datetime.now().time() <= datetime.time(15,30,00) ):
    try:
        name_file = path + str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(':','-').replace(' ','_')
        point_index = name_file.find('.')
        name_file = name_file[:point_index ] + '.xlsx'
        link = 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0'
        resp = requests.get(link)
        output = open(name_file, 'wb')
        output.write(resp.content)
        output.close()    
    
        xl = pd.ExcelFile(name_file)
        print(xl.sheet_names)
        df1 = xl.parse()
        df1.columns = df1.iloc[1]
        df1 = df1.drop(1)
        print(df1.iloc[0][0])
        df1 = df1.drop(0)
        volume = 1000
        volume_str = 'حجم'
        name_str = 'نام'
        df1_volume = df1[df1[volume_str] > 1000][name_str]
        
        time.sleep(5)
        
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Does it works if you run from terminal?

Comment: @iGian: No doesn't stop in Windows 10 terminal too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that you're bypassing all the exceptions by writing:

```
except:
    continue

# which is equivalent to:
except BaseException:
    continue
```

which also includes the exception `KeyboardInterrupt` and the reason to why you can't reliably stop it by using Ctrl + C (a keyboard interrupt).

Although a bad practice, but what you might want is:

```
except Exception:
    continue
```

`Exception` does not include `KeyboardInterrupt`, so Ctrl + C will stop it always.

Check the exception hierarchy [here (Python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) for more information.

A good practice could be to handle exceptions on smaller code blocks, and handling specific exceptions, where you have a reason to believe that the data could be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

To stop your program, in windows just press <kbd>Control</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>.

In a Unix-style shell environment, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend whatever process is currently controlling the console.